# No database filling when using insert into (WPF application)

Tags: database-connection

When I try to use the application to add new rows to my database everything goes OK, but when I close the program the database does not contain the newly inserted row.

Below is my code:

```
string n;
n = txtNaslov.Text;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("my connection string...");

try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Table1 values('" + n + "', con);
    //i ve added the other
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
}
finally
{
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your table have just one column? Maybe there is an exception being thrown? Post the table schema and try to log the exception message.

Comment: Well, your biggest problem is that empty `catch` statement.  Exceptions are thrown for a reason and tend to contain very useful information about problems the system encounters.  _Never_ ignore exceptions.

Comment: Another side notice :` con.Close();` should be in `finally`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to invert some lines...

First Open your cmd and then set your SQL Statement,
this may be wiping out your sql.

Don't discard David's comment, fill catch statement, it can show you what are you donig wrong

Comment: no it has 4 columns but for the example to be more clear i put only one here is the real
new SqlCommand("insert into Table1 values('" + n + "','" + a + "','" + b + "','" + z + "','" + t + "')", con);

Comment: //I TRIED SOMETHING LIKE THIS BUT IT"S still the same 

 
try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd;
            cmd= new SqlCommand("insert into Table1 values('" + n + "','" + a + "','" + b + "','" + z + "','" + t + "')", con);
            
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

Comment: Can i have a 'copy' of string passed as parameter? (the complete insert)